# Are there non-stationary states in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the double-slit experiment, the interference pattern shows the probability of finding the particle (photon or electron) at a given volume. In a given experimental setting, this probability distribution doesn't change with time, so this probability distribution belongs to a stationary quantum state. I think that this doesn't mean that the Hamilton operator belonging to an experimental setting has only one eigenvalue and a single state that belongs to this eigenvalue because the pattern depends on the wavelength of the photon. If we used the superposition of two photons of different wavelengths, we would get a non-stationary interference pattern. Is there such a thing as "the superposition of two photons of different wavelengths"? Or the double-slit experiment can't produce non-stationary states?

Comment: One can say we are observing the superposition of the virtual EM field (forces) in the DSE. The virtual EM field guiding all photons to the bright bands, none to the dark.  Indeed the real photons (energy) can superimpose as they traverse to the screen, but we never observe these superposition directly, we can only observe photon absorbtion.  Per Dirac and others, every photon acts on its own, 2 colours is just 2 observed overlapped patterns, i.e. red + blue = violet.